# Mutexes not working, using queues works. Why?

Tags: ruby, concurrency, synchronization, mutex

In this example I'm looking to sync two `puts`, in a way that the output will be `ababab...`, without any double `a`s or `b`s on the output.

I have three examples for that: Using a queue, using mutexes in memory and using mutex with files. The queue example work just fine, but the mutexes don't.

**I'm not looking for a working code. I'm looking to understand why using a queue it works, and using mutexes don't. By my understanding, they are supposed to be equivalent.**

Queue example: Work.

```
def a
  Thread.new do
    $queue.pop
    puts "a"
    b
  end
end

def b
   Thread.new do
    sleep(rand)
    puts "b"
    $queue << true
  end
end

$queue = Queue.new
$queue << true
loop{a; sleep(rand)}
```

Mutex file example: Don't work.

```
def a
  Thread.new do
    $mutex.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
    puts "a"
    b
  end
end

def b
   Thread.new do
    sleep(rand)
    puts "b"
    $mutex.flock(File::LOCK_UN)
  end
end

MUTEX_FILE_PATH = '/tmp/mutex'
File.open(MUTEX_FILE_PATH, "w") unless File.exists?(MUTEX_FILE_PATH)
$mutex = File.new(MUTEX_FILE_PATH,"r+")
loop{a; sleep(rand)}
```

Mutex variable example: Don't work.

```
def a
  Thread.new do
    $mutex.lock
    puts "a"
    b
  end
end

def b
   Thread.new do
    sleep(rand)
    puts "b"
    $mutex.unlock
  end
end

$mutex = Mutex.new
loop{a; sleep(rand)}
```

Comment: @sawa take a look in this question

Comment: Aw, I didn't get the bounty? Glad to have helped, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**
Your use of the mutex is incorrect. With `Queue`, you can populate with one thread and then `pop` it with another, but you cannot lock a `Mutex` with one one thread and then unlock with another.

As @matt explained, there are several subtle things happening like the mutex getting unlocked automatically and the silent exceptions you don't see.

**How Mutexes Are Commonly Used**
*Mutexes are used to access a particular shared resource, like a variable or a file.* The synchronization of variables and files consequently allow multiple threads to be synchronized. Mutexes don't really synchronize threads by themselves.

For example:

1. `thread_a` and `thread_b` could be synchronized via a shared boolean variable such as `true_a_false_b`.
2. You'd have to access, test, and toggle that boolean variable every time you use it - a multistep process.
3. It's necessary to ensure that this multistep process occurs atomically, i.e. is not interrupted. This is when you would use a mutex. A trivialized example follows:

```
require 'thread'
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
true_a_false_b = true
mutex = Mutex.new

thread_a = Thread.new do
  loop do
    mutex.lock
    if true_a_false_b
      puts "a"
      true_a_false_b = false
    end
    mutex.unlock
  end
end

thread_b = Thread.new do
  loop do
    mutex.lock
    if !true_a_false_b
      puts "b"
      true_a_false_b = true
    end
    mutex.unlock
  end

sleep(1) # if in irb/console, yield the "current" thread to thread_a and thread_b
```

Answer (score 2):

In your mutex example, the thread created in method `b` sleeps for a while, prints `b` then tries to unlock the mutex. This isn’t legal, a thread cannot unlock a mutex unless it already holds that lock, and raises an ThreadError if you try:

```
m = Mutex.new
m.unlock
```

results in:

```
release.rb:2:in `unlock': Attempt to unlock a mutex which is not locked (ThreadError)
        from release.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

You won’t see this in your example because [by default Ruby silently ignores exceptions raised in threads other than the main thread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Thread.html#class-Thread-label-Exception+handling). You can change this using [`Thread::abort_on_exception=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Thread.html#method-c-abort_on_exception-3D) – if you add

```
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
```

to the top of your file you’ll see something like:

```
a
b
with-mutex.rb:15:in `unlock': Attempt to unlock a mutex which is not locked (ThreadError)
        from with-mutex.rb:15:in `block in b'
```

(you might see more than one `a`, but there’ll only be one `b`).

In the `a` method you create threads that acquire a lock, print `a`, call another method (that creates a new thread and returns straight away) and then terminate. It doesn’t seem to be well documented but when a thread terminates it releases any locks it has, so in this case the lock is released almost immediately allowing other `a` threads to run.

Overall the lock doesn’t have much effect. It doesn’t prevent the `b` threads from running at all, and whilst it does prevent two `a` threads running at the same time, it is released as soon as the thread holding it exits.

I think you might be thinking of [*semaphores*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)), and whilst the Ruby docs say [“Mutex implements a simple semaphore”](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Mutex.html) they are [not quite the same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Semaphores_vs._mutexes).

Ruby doesn’t provide semaphores in the standard library, but it does provide [condition variables](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/ConditionVariable.html). (That link goes to the older 2.0.0 docs. The `thread` standard library is required by default in Ruby 2.1+, and the move seems to have resulted in the current docs not being available. Also be aware that Ruby also has a separate [monitor](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/monitor/rdoc/Monitor.html) library which (I think) adds the same features (mutexes and condition variables) in a more object-orientated fashion.)

Using condition variables and mutexes you can control the coordination between threads. [Uri Agassi’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23679239/214790) shows one possible way to do that (although I think there’s a race condition with how his solution gets started).

If you look at the [source for Queue](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_481/lib/thread.rb#L119-L251) (again this is a link to 2.0.0 – the thread library has been converted to C in recent versions and the Ruby version is easier to follow) you can see that it is implemented with [`Mutex`es](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_481/lib/thread.rb#L155) and [`ConditionVariables`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_481/lib/thread.rb#L156). When you call `$queue.pop` in the `a` thread in your queue example you end up calling [`wait` on the mutex](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_481/lib/thread.rb#L196) in the same way as Uri Agassi’s answer calls `$cv.wait($mutex)` in his method `a`. Similarly when you call `$queue << true` in your `b` thread you end up [calling `signal` on the condition variable](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_481/lib/thread.rb#L166) in the same way as Uri Agassi’s calls `$cv.signal` in his `b` thread.

The main reason your file locking example doesn’t work is that file locking provides a way for multiple *processes* to coordinate with each other (usually so only one tries to write to a file at the same time) and doesn’t help with coordinating *threads* within a process. Your file locking code is structured in a similar way to the mutex example so it’s likely it would suffer the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with file-based version has not been sorted out properly.
The reason why it does not work is that `f.flock(File::LOCK_EX)` does not block if called on the same file `f` multiple times.
This can be checked with this simple sequential program:

```
require 'thread'

MUTEX_FILE_PATH = '/tmp/mutex'
$fone= File.new( MUTEX_FILE_PATH, "w")
$ftwo= File.open( MUTEX_FILE_PATH)

puts "start"
$fone.flock( File::LOCK_EX)
puts "locked"
$fone.flock( File::LOCK_EX)
puts "so what"
$ftwo.flock( File::LOCK_EX)
puts "dontcare"
```

which prints everything except `dontcare`.

So the file-based program does not work because

```
$mutex.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
```

never blocks.

Comment: I didn't got this one. Why would I want to release the lock on `b`? Since `b` is always called by `a`, can't I lock only the entrance of `a` and unlock after `puts b` is called?

Comment: `a` creates multiple threads. But as `$mutex` is a global variable, the threads created by `a` do not lock at all regardless of whether `b` unlocks or not.